# Is there a function to check whether an element exists in a list?

Tags: racket

In racket, I'm aware of the `member` function which returns the first occurrence of an element if it exists or `#f` otherwise, but is there a function which just returns `#t` or `#f` for whether the element exists in a list?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer to this question is `member`. In Racket, everything that is not `#f` is true. Therefore, `member` works just fine for testing the presence of an element in a list:

```
> (if (member 3 '(1 2 3)) 'present 'absent)
'present
> (if (member 3 '(1 2)) 'present 'absent)
'absent
```

There’s no need to specifically produce `#t` upon success because everything in Racket that branches only cares about `#f` and non-`#f` values.

There are some rare situations in which you really do want a boolean value, such as if you are going to store the result in some data structure and don’t want to retain an unnecessary reference to the list. The usual idiom for doing this in Racket is `(and v #t)`, where `v` is some value, since this is equivalent to writing `(if v #t #f)`. Therefore, you could just surround your call to `member` with that:

```
> (and (member 3 '(1 2 3)) #t)
#t
```

Since this is so rarely necessary, this is more idiomatic in Racket than writing a separate `member?` function.

Comment: I ended up similarly using `(list? (member 3 '(1 2 3)))` but it's good to know that I don't even need to do that because the list will be counted as #t for not being #f.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think there's a standard function for this, but see [`true?`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/predicates/index.html?q=true%3F#%28def._%28%28lib._predicates%2Fmain..rkt%29._true~3f%29%29) and [`without-truthiness`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/predicates/index.html?q=true%3F#%28def._%28%28lib._predicates%2Fmain..rkt%29._without-truthiness%29%29) in the [*predicates*](https://docs.racket-lang.org/predicates/) library.

Defining `true?` is pretty easy:

```
(define (true? x)
    (if x #t #f))
```